# VScode/Github extenssion issue

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm encountering the folloing issue in VSCode where I've made some changes in a folder of a project and it appears like so in VSCode **Source Control** panel. It is supposed to be a folder, not that type of folder, I think.

I tryed to push it to github but I can't open that folder it appears like in the third image.

Also, it's blocking me form pushing it to git, discard the changes or anything else.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Did someone experienced this before ?

Edit 2:

I've cloned the repo from github and the folder directory is empty.

[image]

Running `git status` inside the local frontend folder gave me this:

[image]

But those files don't appear in **Source Control** view.

Comment: What's the issue? This screenshot is hard to see, I'm just noticing a modified file in git.

Comment: Hi @NickMcCurdy, sorry for the bad explanation. I added some edits and hope it makes more sense now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's really not clear what the screenshots are showing. How about opening a console window, changing to a folder within your clone repo and running `git status`

Comment: I'm quite new to using stack, please excuse me again and have a look now.

Comment: you have a repository `next-app` and a repository `frontend`. Do you have a repo inside a repo (a `.git` directory inside a sibling directory of another `.git` directory)? All the new files you see with `git status` are `nextapp` files.

Comment: I don't really know what I have there, from git perspective. It's possible that I messed up something when I tried to load it for the first time. I just had a `next-app` folder with `frontend` and `backend` and wanted to make this a repos inside git as a whole. Simply to upload both back/frontends. Is there a way to revert from this?

Comment: It looks like frontend is a submodule. Do you need it to be a separate git repository that's also part of next-app, or do you want to destroy the frontend repository and add its files to next-app?

Comment: I want to destroy the frontend repo and it should be just a folder in next-app repo. I'm also having there a backend folder. I just need both frontend and backend folder to be inside the same repo